# Combinar dos registros de una tabla e insertarlos en una columna vacía

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, transact-sql

Al ejecutar mi script en la tabla CheckInOut

```
select UserDeviceId, substring(replace (convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,103),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar,FechaCompleta,108),':',''),1,12) as DATE_FORMAT_STRING 
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] 
WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'
```

me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera juntar los dos registros en uno e insertarlo en otra columna vacía de otra tabla, también si se pudiera agregar "00" o "0" cuando el dato es menor que 8 al lado izquierdo de la columna "UserDeviced" dejándome un total de 20 números al combinar ambos registros.

Comment: Estás tratando de violar la primera regla de normalización. Esa es una mala idea en muchos sentidos. Necesitas mantener valores atómicos en cada columna para que puedas manejarlos de una forma más simple. El formato de fecha también debería ser reajustado para que pueda mantener un mejor órden YYYYMMDDHHMI

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir ceros a la izquierda si el dato del campo UserDeviceId tiene menos de 8 dígitos puedes hace

```
FORMAT(UserDeviceId,'0000000#')
```

Para concatenar los dos campos simplemente utilizas un `+`

```
select UserDeviceId, substring(replace (convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,103),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar,FechaCompleta,108),':',''),1,12) as DATE_FORMAT_STRING 
, FORMAT(UserDeviceId,'0000000#') + substring(replace (convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,103),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar,FechaCompleta,108),':',''),1,12) as NuevoCampoCombinado
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] 
WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'
```